# Change boolean field from parent class to child class - Odoo v8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Consider this:

```
@api.multi
@api.onchange('order_lines', 'order_lines.is_book_block', '')
@api.constrains('order_lines', 'order_lines.isbn')
def check_quantity(self):
    location = self.printer_book_block.property_stock_supplier.id
    for rec in self:
        if rec.order_lines:
            for line in rec.order_lines:
                if line.qty > line.isbn.with_context({ 'location': location, }).qty_available >= 0:#line.isbn.qty_available in location:
                    rec.write({'state': 'awaitingraw'})
                else:
                    rec.write({'state': 'work_in_progress', 'is_book_block': True})
```

When there is enough product quantity (isbn) on the specified location, change state of the document to `work_in_progess` and also change Boolean field `is_book_block` to `True`.

The `state` field is on the parent model:

```
class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
_name = 'bsi.print.order'

@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    if vals.get('name', 'New') == 'New':
        vals['name'] = self.env['ir.sequence'].next_by_code('bsi.print.order') or '/'
    return super(bsi_print_order, self).create(vals)

name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")
book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Book Block", default=True)
binding = fields.Boolean(string="Binding")
edging = fields.Boolean(string="Edging")
state = fields.Selection([
        ('draft','Draft'),
        ('awaitingraw','Awaiting raw materials'),
        ('work_in_progress','Print in Progress'),
        ('delivered','Delivered'),
        ('cancel','Cancel'),
    ], string="State")
```

The `is_book_block` field is on the child class `One2many order_lines field`:

```
class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity")
is_book_block = fields.Boolean(string="Is Book Block Done")
is_binding = fields.Boolean(string="Is Binding Done")
is_edging = fields.Boolean(string="Is Edging Done")
isbns = fields.Many2one('worksheets.isbns', string="Worksheet ISBNS")
```

There are also other two fields `is_binding` and `is_edging`.

Anyways, knowing one is sufficient to figure out the other two (I guess, lol) so, since `state` is on the parent class, it works nicely, the state of the record actually changes, however, while there is no syntax error with `is_book_block` it should change to `True`, but it doesn't, so, I think this is because the method is looping on `order_lines` but it changes things on parent class only (bsi.production.order).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i understand the `is_book_block`is in the line when you loop through lines every line is a record it self you call write if you want to set more than field or just change that field:

```
  # when you change just one field no need for write just 
  rec.state = 'work_in_progress' # is enough
  # because rec.state will trigger write method
  # but for more than one field use write to trigger it only one time
  # line is a record too you can call write also if you want
  line.is_book_block = True
```

One thing remove `order_lines.is_book_block`from onchange decorator because you will trigger an infinitive call for the the method :

```
  @api.onchange('order_lines')
```